# not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, header, arduino

An error occurred during the uploading the code to Arduino Atmega2560.

The errors are:

```
herkulex.cpp: In member function 'void herkulex::hklx_SendPacket(DrsPacket)':
herkulex.cpp:121: error: 'USART0_PutNChar' was not declared in this scope
herkulex.cpp: In member function 'unsigned char herkulex::hklx_ucReceivePacket(DrsPacket*)':
herkulex.cpp:211: error: 'USART0_ucGetNChar' was not declared in this scope
herkulex.cpp: In member function 'void herkulex::hklx_RemoveInvalidData()':
herkulex.cpp:244: error: 'USART0_ucTrashNChar' was not declared in this scope
```

Below is the code where the error occurred: (herkulex.cpp code)

```
#include<Arduino.h>
#include<Wire.h>
#include<Math.h> 

//ATmega128ì�˜ ë ˆì§€ìŠ¤í„° ë“±ì�´ ì •ì�˜ë�˜ì–´ ìžˆì�Œ
#include <avr/io.h>
//#include "TIMER0.h"
#include "USART0.h" 
//#include "USART0.c"

//#define __HERKULEX_C
#include "herkulex.h"
//#undef __HERKULEX_C

//void hklx_RemoveInvalidData(void);
#define herkulex_cpp

herkulex::herkulex()
{
  // Empty constructor. needed for lib
}



#define USART_BUF_SIZE 256  
#define PROTOCOL_SIZE_IDX 2
#define PROTOCOL_ID_IDX   3
#define PROTOCOL_CMD_IDX  4
#define PROTOCOL_CS1_IDX  5
#define PROTOCOL_CS2_IDX  6
#define PROTOCOL_DATA_IDX  7

//í—¤ë�” ê´€ë ¨
#define HEADER      0xFF

//SIZE ê´€ë ¨
#define MIN_PACKET_SIZE     7
#define MIN_ACK_PACKET_SIZE                 9
#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE                     223
#define MAX_DATA_SIZE                       (MAX_PACKET_SIZE-MIN_PACKET_SIZE)

//ID ê´€ë ¨
#define MAX_ID                              0xFD    
#define BROADCAST_ID                        0xFE  

//CMD ê´€ë ¨ - Request Packet
#define CMD_EEP_WRITE                       0x01
#define CMD_EEP_READ                        0x02
#define CMD_RAM_WRITE                       0x03
#define CMD_RAM_READ                        0x04    
    #define CMD_RW_DATA_ADDR_IDX            7
    #define CMD_RW_DATA_LEN_IDX             8
#define CMD_I_JOG                           0x05
    #define CMD_I_JOG_STRUCT_SIZE           5
    #define CMD_I_JOG_MAX_DRS               (MAX_DATA_SIZE/CMD_I_JOG_STRUCT_SIZE)
#define CMD_S_JOG                           0x06
    #define CMD_S_JOG_STRUCT_SIZE           4
    #define CMD_S_JOG_MAX_DRS               (MAX_DATA_SIZE/CMD_S_JOG_STRUCT_SIZE)
#define CMD_STAT                            0x07    
#define CMD_ROLLBACK                        0x08
#define CMD_REBOOT                          0x09

#define CMD_MIN                             (CMD_EEP_WRITE)
#define CMD_MAX                             (CMD_REBOOT)

//CMD ê´€ë ¨ - ACK Packet
#define CMD_ACK_MASK                        0x40

#define CMD_EEP_WRITE_ACK                   (CMD_EEP_WRITE|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_EEP_READ_ACK                    (CMD_EEP_READ|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_RAM_WRITE_ACK                   (CMD_RAM_WRITE|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_RAM_READ_ACK                    (CMD_RAM_READ|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_I_JOG_ACK                       (CMD_I_JOG|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_S_JOG_ACK                       (CMD_S_JOG|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_STAT_ACK                        (CMD_STAT|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_ROLLBACK_ACK                    (CMD_ROLLBACK|CMD_ACK_MASK)
#define CMD_REBOOT_ACK                      (CMD_REBOOT|CMD_ACK_MASK)

#define CMD_ACK_MIN                         (CMD_EEP_WRITE_ACK)
#define CMD_ACK_MAX                         (CMD_REBOOT_ACK)

//CheckSum ê´€ë ¨
#define CHKSUM_MASK                         0xFE



//////////////////////////////receiving state result value //////////////////////////////
  enum{
    DRS_RXWAITING,
    DRS_RXCOMPLETE,
    DRS_HEADERNOTFOUND,
    DRS_INVALIDSIZE,
    DRS_UNKNOWNCMD,
    DRS_INVALIDID,
    DRS_CHKSUMERROR,
    DRS_RXTIMEOUT
  }DrsRxStatus;

void herkulex:: hklx_Init(unsigned long ulBaudRate){
//  TIMER0_Init();
//  USART0_Init(ulBaudRate);
    return;
}
#define HEADER      0xFF
void herkulex:: hklx_SendPacket(DrsPacket stPacket){
    unsigned char i;

    //í—¤ë�” ìž…ë ¥
    stPacket.ucHeader[0] = HEADER;
    stPacket.ucHeader[1] = HEADER;

    //CheckSum ê³„ì‚° í›„ ìž…ë ¥
    stPacket.ucCheckSum1 = stPacket.ucPacketSize ^ stPacket.ucChipID ^ stPacket.ucCmd;
    for( i=0; i<(stPacket.ucPacketSize-MIN_PACKET_SIZE); i++ )    
        stPacket.ucCheckSum1 ^= stPacket.unData.ucData[i];

    stPacket.ucCheckSum2 = ~(stPacket.ucCheckSum1);
    stPacket.ucCheckSum1 &= CHKSUM_MASK;    
    stPacket.ucCheckSum2 &= CHKSUM_MASK;

    //PacketSize ë§Œí�¼ USART0ìœ¼ë¡œ ì†¡ì‹ 
    USART0_PutNChar(&stPacket.ucHeader[0], stPacket.ucPacketSize);

    return;
}

unsigned char herkulex:: hklx_ucReceivePacket(DrsPacket *pstPacket){
    unsigned char i, ucPacketSize, ucChipID, ucCmd, ucReadLen, ucCheckSum1, ucCheckSum2;

    //ë°›ì�€ ë�°ì�´í„° ìˆ˜ê°€ ACK íŒ¨í‚·ì�˜ ìµœì†Œ ì‚¬ì�´ì¦ˆë³´ë‹¤ ì �ì�„ ê²½ìš°
    if(gucRxBufferCnt < MIN_ACK_PACKET_SIZE){
        return DRS_RXWAITING;
    }

    //íŒ¨í‚·ì�˜ ì²˜ì�Œ ë‘� ë°”ì�´íŠ¸ê°€ í—¤ë�”ê°€ ì•„ë‹� ê²½ìš°
    if(gucRxBuffer[gucRxBufferReadIdx] != HEADER || 
       gucRxBuffer[((unsigned int)gucRxBufferReadIdx+1)%USART_BUF_SIZE] != HEADER){
        hklx_RemoveInvalidData();
        return DRS_HEADERNOTFOUND;   
    }
    //ë§žì�„ ê²½ìš° Size, ID, Cmdë¥¼ ì�½ì–´ì˜´
    else{
        ucPacketSize = gucRxBuffer[ ((unsigned int)gucRxBufferReadIdx + PROTOCOL_SIZE_IDX ) % USART_BUF_SIZE ];
        ucChipID = gucRxBuffer[ ((unsigned int)gucRxBufferReadIdx + PROTOCOL_ID_IDX ) % USART_BUF_SIZE ];
        ucCmd = gucRxBuffer[ ((unsigned int)gucRxBufferReadIdx + PROTOCOL_CMD_IDX ) % USART_BUF_SIZE ];
    }

    //Sizeê°€ ìµœëŒ€ë³´ë‹¤ í�´ ê²½ìš°
    if(ucPacketSize > MAX_PACKET_SIZE){
        hklx_RemoveInvalidData();
        return DRS_INVALIDSIZE;
    }
    //ì•„ì§� Size ë§Œí�¼ì�˜ ë�°ì�´í„°ê°€ ë“¤ì–´ì˜¤ì§€ ì•Šì•˜ì�„ ê²½ìš°
    else if(ucPacketSize > gucRxBufferCnt){
        return DRS_RXWAITING;
    }

    //Cmdê°€ ë²”ìœ„ë¥¼ ë²—ì–´ë‚œ ê²½ìš°
    if(!(ucCmd >= CMD_ACK_MIN && ucCmd <= CMD_ACK_MAX)){
        hklx_RemoveInvalidData();
        return DRS_UNKNOWNCMD;
    }

    //IDê°€ ë²”ìœ„ë¥¼ ë²—ì–´ë‚œ ê²½ìš°
    if(ucChipID >= BROADCAST_ID){
        hklx_RemoveInvalidData();
        return DRS_INVALIDID;
    }

    //ê°� Cmdì—� ë”°ë�¼ì„œ Sizeê°€ ì �í•©í•œì§€ ê²€ì‚¬
    switch(ucCmd){
        case CMD_EEP_WRITE_ACK:
        case CMD_RAM_WRITE_ACK:
        case CMD_I_JOG_ACK:
        case CMD_S_JOG_ACK:
        case CMD_STAT_ACK:
        case CMD_ROLLBACK_ACK:
        case CMD_REBOOT_ACK:
            if(ucPacketSize != MIN_ACK_PACKET_SIZE){
                hklx_RemoveInvalidData();
                return DRS_INVALIDSIZE;
            }
            break;
        case CMD_EEP_READ_ACK:
        case CMD_RAM_READ_ACK:
            ucReadLen = gucRxBuffer[ ((unsigned int)gucRxBufferReadIdx + CMD_RW_DATA_LEN_IDX ) % USART_BUF_SIZE ];
            if(ucPacketSize != (MIN_ACK_PACKET_SIZE + 2 + ucReadLen)){
                hklx_RemoveInvalidData();
                return DRS_INVALIDSIZE;
            }   
            break;
    }

    //ìˆ˜ì‹ ë�œ íŒ¨í‚·ì�˜ CheckSumì�„ ê³„ì‚°
    ucCheckSum1 = ucPacketSize ^ ucChipID ^ ucCmd;
    for(i=0;i<(ucPacketSize-MIN_PACKET_SIZE);i++){
        ucCheckSum1 ^= gucRxBuffer[ ((unsigned int)gucRxBufferReadIdx + i ) % USART_BUF_SIZE ];
    }
    ucCheckSum2 = ~(ucCheckSum1);
    ucCheckSum1 &= CHKSUM_MASK;
    ucCheckSum2 &= CHKSUM_MASK;

    //ê³„ì‚°ë�œ CheckSumì�´ ì‹¤ì œë¡œ ë°›ì�€ ë�°ì�´í„°ì™€ ì�¼ì¹˜í•˜ëŠ”ì§€ ê²€ì‚¬
    if(ucCheckSum1 != gucRxBuffer[ ((unsigned int)gucRxBufferReadIdx + PROTOCOL_CS1_IDX) % USART_BUF_SIZE ] ||
       ucCheckSum2 != gucRxBuffer[ ((unsigned int)gucRxBufferReadIdx + PROTOCOL_CS2_IDX) % USART_BUF_SIZE ])
    {
        hklx_RemoveInvalidData();
        return DRS_CHKSUMERROR;
    }       

    //ëª¨ë“  ê²€ì‚¬ë¥¼ í†µê³¼í–ˆë‹¤ë©´, ë°›ëŠ” pstPacketì—� íŒ¨í‚·ì�„ ë³µì‚¬
    USART0_ucGetNChar(&(pstPacket->ucHeader[0]), ucPacketSize);

    //ì™„ë£Œ ìƒ�íƒœë¥¼ ë°˜í™˜
    return DRS_RXCOMPLETE;
}

void herkulex:: hklx_RemoveInvalidData(void){
    unsigned char ucRcvCnt, ucRdIndex, i;

    //ë²„í�¼ì�˜ ìƒ�íƒœë¥¼ ë³€ìˆ˜ì—� ë³µì‚¬
    ucRcvCnt=gucRxBufferCnt;
    ucRdIndex=gucRxBufferReadIdx;

    //ë°›ì�€ ë�°ì�´í„°ê°€ ì—†ì�„ ê²½ìš° ë°˜í™˜
    if(ucRcvCnt==0){
        return;
    }

    //ë‹¤ì�Œ í—¤ë�”ë¥¼ ì°¾ê±°ë‚˜ ë°›ì�€ ë�°ì�´í„°ì�˜ ë��ì—� ë�„ë‹¬í•  ë•Œê¹Œì§€ ì§„í–‰

    for(i=1;i<ucRcvCnt-1;i++){
        if( (gucRxBuffer[ ((unsigned int)ucRdIndex + i ) % USART_BUF_SIZE ] == HEADER ) &&
            (gucRxBuffer[ ((unsigned int)ucRdIndex + i + 1) % USART_BUF_SIZE ] == HEADER) )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if((i==ucRcvCnt-1) && (gucRxBuffer[ ((unsigned int)ucRdIndex + ucRcvCnt - 1) % USART_BUF_SIZE ] != HEADER))
    {
        i++;
    }       

    //ië§Œí�¼ ë�°ì�´í„°ë¥¼ ë²„ë¦¼
    USART0_ucTrashNChar(i);     

    return;
}
```

The variables that the error stated that they were not declared were all declared under USART0.h file which i have included in the herkulex.cpp file. May i know what's wrong with the codes? THanks!

```
USART0.h code: 
#ifndef USART0_lib
#define USART0_lib

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <inttypes.h>
//ìˆ˜ì‹  ë²„í�¼ì�˜ ì‚¬ì�´ì¦ˆ ì„ ì–¸
#define USART_BUF_SIZE 256

//ìˆ˜ì‹  ë²„í�¼, ì�½ê¸° ì�¸ë�±ìŠ¤, ì“°ê¸° ì�¸ë�±ìŠ¤, ë�°ì�´í„° ìˆ˜ë¥¼ ì €ìž¥í•  ë³€ìˆ˜ ì„ ì–¸
volatile unsigned char gucRxBuffer[USART_BUF_SIZE];
volatile unsigned char gucRxBufferReadIdx;
volatile unsigned char gucRxBufferWriteIdx;
volatile unsigned char gucRxBufferCnt;

#ifdef USART0_cpp
#define EXTERN 
#else 
#define EXTERN extern 
#endif 

class USART0
{
  public: 
  USART0();

  void USART0_Init(unsigned long ulBaudRate);
  void USART0_PutChar(unsigned char ucData);
  void USART0_PutNChar(unsigned char *pucData, unsigned char ucCnt);
  unsigned char USART0_ucGetNChar(unsigned char *pucTarget, unsigned char ucCnt);
  unsigned char USART0_ucTrashNChar(unsigned char ucCnt);
  void USART0_ClearBuffer(void);

//  private :no private
};


#endif
```

Comment: `//ë²„í�¼ì�˜ ìƒ�íƒœë¥¼ ë³€ìˆ˜ì—� ë³µì‚¬` What's up with the comments?

Comment: it's in other languages that's why. i got this code from the webpage of manufacturer to control the device.

Comment: Encoding, rather than language. They could maybe even be helpful if you `iconv` the file.

Comment: ohok thanks for the tip! so where do i insert the iconv?

Comment: You don't insert an `iconv`, it's a command line utility (and library) to convert files or buffers from one encoding to another. If you have a Linux system (probably Solaris or BSD too), `man iconv` tells you how to use it. Otherwise, on Windows, you might have it if you have a Cygwin or MinGW. Otherwise, there are probably tools on the net, but whether it's worth bothering is doubtful.

Answer (score 0):

`USART0_PutChar` is a member function of class `USART0` . You are trying to call this from another class member function in the same way as standalone a non-member function - You need an instance of `USART0` to call the function on.

In relation to your comment, you would need to create an instance of `USART0` then call the function like you would any other member function

```
 USART0 obj;
 obj.USART0_PutChar();
```

You cannot call a member function like you are trying to currently unless you are calling it from another member function **of the same class**. You might be able to achieve what you want by passing an instance of `USART0` (or pointer or reference to one) as an argument to the function in which you need to call `USART0_PutChar()`. Alternatively you could consider making this function a static member function of `USART0` although that may be unsuitable depending on whether or not the function requires access to non-static member variables.

Comment: how do i create an instance of USART0 in the USART0.h file?

Answer (score 0):

The function `USART0_PutNChar` (and the others) are *member functions* of another class. You need to create an instance of that class and call the functions through this object:

```
USART0 usart0;

usart0.USART0_PutNChar(...);
```

However, it seems like the class `USART0` doesn't contain any state, which means you can either make the functions global (i.e. not in a class); Make the functions static, as in

```
// Using `struct` as there is no private or protected data/functions
struct USART0
{
    static void USART0_PutNChar(...);
    ...
};
```

And the third alternative is to make `USART0` into a namespace:

```
namespace USART0
{
    void USART0_PutNChar(...);
    ...
}
```

In these last two cases you call the functions like this:

```
USART0::USART0_PutNChar(...);
```

Comment: ok it helped to eliminate the problem but a new error occurred which says that "multiple definition of `usart0". Why does this occur and what should i do now?

Comment: @shannon It's because you declared a variable `usart0` multiple times in a function? It's only needed once per function, or as a single global variable.

Comment: in the .cpp file, how do you declare usart? if i uses namespace (third alternative)